# update a column with a value coming from an inner join

Tags: php, mysql

i need to update a lot of db values, so i guess it's better to use a sql statement, maybe creating and uploading a php file and running it from time to time.

in my db i have 3 related tables, let's say

```
tableA_label
tableB_image
tableC_text
```

the relations are as follows:

```
tableaA_label.ImageID refers to tableB_image.ID

tableB_image.TextID refers to tableC_text.ID
```

my goal is:

```
update tableA_label.Name

tableA_label.Name = tableC_text.title

where 

tableC_text.ID = tableB_image.TextID 

and

tableB_image.ID = tableA_label.ImageID

.....
```

how can accomplish this using an sql statement?

thank you for supporting

Comment: create your all your stuff in php file and call the php file time to time using cron job

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE tableA_label SET
tableA_label.Name = (SELECT TableC_text.title FROM TableC_text INNER 
JOIN  TableB_image ON  TableB_image.TextID = TableC_text.ID
WHERE TableB_image.ID = tableA_label.imageID)
```

Comment: thank you, that's what i needed, worked 100%, i appreciated your help

Comment: You are very welcome :) , kindly accept the answer so any one will have the same problem can know the correct answer.